# Python dict of lists of tuples. print list of element from tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python like:

```
{1: [('type', 'USB'), ('ipaddress', '192.168.1.1'), ('hostname', 'hello'), ('realname', 'world')], 2: [('type', 'Stereo'), ('ipaddress', '192.168.1.2'), ('hostname', 'hi'), ('realname', 'mum')]}
```

how would I print a list in the key order (1, 2 etc.) of say the hostnames so the output would be:

```
hello
hi
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by key order?  Dictionaries in python are not ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that converts the inner pair-list into a dictionary.  That has the advantage that it will work regardless of the position of the *hostname* entry:

```
>>> for order, pairs in sorted(d.items()):
        print dict(pairs)['hostname']


hello
hi
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```
>>> d = {1: [('type', 'USB'), ('ipaddress', '192.168.1.1'), ('hostname', 'hello'), ('realname', 'world')], 2: [('type', 'Stereo'), ('ipaddress', '192.168.1.2'), ('hostname', 'hi'), ('realname', 'mum')]}

>>> for i in sorted(d.keys()):
    ...     print d[i][2][1]
    ... 
    hello
    hi
```

What you basically do is pick the dictionary keys, sort them, then use them to print your hostname tuple from the dict in order.

(I assume that the ('hostname', string) tuple is always in the same location)

Comment: // , That produces the expected output in Python 2.7.10 on Mac OSX El Capitan.